# How to get socket.io to only listen on one specific route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm only wanting socket.io to listen on my /home route but it seems to be listening on every route? Is there a way to get it only to listen to my /home route? This is what I have:

```
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

This is what I've tried, but this just displays a JSON file on the home path

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000, {
  path: '/home',
  serveClient: true,
  // below are engine.IO options
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  cookie: false
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "listen on only one route".  A client's Javascript either connects to the socket.io server or it doesn't - it's binary.  There's no use for multiple routes like there are with http requests.  socket.io supports connecting and listening for a particular namespace if you wanted multiple separate connection "channels" for multiple connections.

Comment: Ok so it just listens to everything on the site when the site is loaded? How do I only change things on one of my pages if it is listening to the whole site? Or does that not slow things down?

Comment: You either use different Javascript in some of your pages or you have your common Javascript check the path of the page and only connect on socket.io for specific page paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm only wanting socket.io to listen on my /home route but it seems to be listening on every route? Is there a way to get it only to listen to my /home route?

A client's Javascript either connects to the socket.io server or it doesn't - it's binary. There's no use for multiple routes like there are with http requests. socket.io supports connecting and listening for a particular namespace if you wanted multiple separate connection "channels" for multiple connections.

> Ok so it just listens to everything on the site when the site is loaded? How do I only change things on one of my pages if it is listening to the whole site? Or does that not slow things down?

A socket.io server just listens for incoming connections.  It is not associated with a route.

To have only some of your pages connect on socket.io, you either use different Javascript in some of your pages or you have your common Javascript check the path of the page and only connect on socket.io for specific page paths.

For example, you could have this in your web page Javascript:

```
var socket;
if (window.location.pathname === "/home") {
     socket = io();
     socket.on(...);
}
```

This would allow your common Javascript (that is present in many pages) to only create a socket.io connection in your `/home` page.

Comment: So when I open a connection to socket.io it listens to the whole site but I can change the functionality based on different js files? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @Bkes - See the additional info in my answer.  The server just listens for incoming connection requests.  It does not know what page those connections come from.  So, it is the client that must decide whether to connect or not.  That can either be done with Javascript logic (by looking at what page is currently loaded) or by putting different Javascript into only the pages that you want socket.io to connect from.